# Should I deploy a front-end MDE file instead of an MDB? What might be the benefits?

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, frontend, backend

Yesterday I split our database and placed the FE and BE on a shared drive for other people to access. The FE is an .accdb file but in all of my research I'm to assume that's the same as MDB?

I need to be able to edit the forms and queries while other users are accessing the FE. I deployed a very basic FE for them to use but now I need to make it more robust. I currently can't do that without receiving an error message about not having exclusive access.

So I have a couple of questions in regards to the treatment of this database now.

1) If I move the FE, will it still be linked to the BE? If I move the BE will that alter the file path and corrupt the links, making the FE unusable?

2) Are .accdb and MDB synonymous or am I well off the beaten path here? I understand that MDB is used to make edits/changes while you're meant to provide your users with an MDE version.

3) Is the file conversion an option within the database? Is there a tab or button on the ribbon that creates an MDE version? Are there are downsides or potential issues with 4-5 people accessing the MDE and will it remain linked to the BE if I move it?

4) Once I've made the desired changes to the MDB, am I supposed to overwrite the MDE or just make a new one, place it on the shared drive and point the users there?

Thank you all for the help. I haven't gone to school for Database Management. I was thrown into this job and I'm doing my best to stay afloat. This is all fairly new to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1

Yes, moving the FE to different computers means the linked tables will still point to the back end. Because of this, you should link using UNC path names. Eg: \server\AccessApplication\MyApp.accDE

## 2

Mdb = accDB. Sure they are much the same. Accdb is simply a newer format introduced from 2007 onwards. I certainly recommend you convert an mdb to this newer format. We are near 2017 and thus using a 10 year old format is a bad idea.

The above issue is separate from that of using an mde, or now of course an accDE. An accDE is a compiled version of your application with the source code stripped out. You cannot make design changes to the VBA code nor to forms/reports. So it is recommended that you distribute a compiled application that prevents users from making changes. The other HUGE benefit is that un-handled errors don’t blow out variables (VBA variables are NEVER lost nor re-set in a compiled appclations). Needless to say an application that never re-sets variables (even with un-handled errors) results in a far more reliable application. This also means you can have application wide settings in VBA variables, and they are NEVER re-set or lose their values during that given session.

## 3

To compile your application, you should first do a debug->compile while in the VBA editor. If you have no errors, then you can use file->save -> accDE to create and save the compiled version of your application. It is this resulting compiled application that you distribute to each workstation.

## 4

Yes, just like when you receive a new version of a program, say like the PDF viewer, you deploy the next new great version of your application by overwriting the previous version.

So after you split and deploy the accDE to each workstation, you are now free to work on your next great software release, and you be working on the accDB front end. When you tested and are happy with this accDB, then you compile + create the accDE and that is then distributed to each user/workstation.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you move the FE, it will still be linked to the BE. If you move the BE, then the FE will not be able to find the BE and will not have access to it until you relink the tables using the Linked tables tool.
2. Mdb is microsoft's Access old database format. accdb is the current format and has more functionality than a mdb file. Both act in the same way. mde format is the compiled version of an mdb file, it has no development environment, accdb also has a compiled format named accde. This compiled formats are useful to distribute the FE so the users can't make direct changes to linked tables or vba/macro procedures.
3. To save as another format you must use the `save as` button in access. Then you can select what format you'd like to save it to. If your database is currently in mdb format, you will get the mde option. If your database is accdb format you will get accde option. Moving the MDE will not affect the links.
4. Both options are fine. The compiled versions should not be shared through the network, they should be copied into user's computers so the application execution doesn't have to go through the network.

You can read the following sites to better understand database development and deployment.

[Develop and deploy Acc2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738918/how-to-continuously-develop-and-deploy-an-access-2010-database-application)
[Best practices](http://www.opengatesw.net/ms-access-tutorials/Access-Articles/MSAccess-Deployment-Best-Practices.htm)