# Why do MS Access front-ends increase in size over time?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, frontend, filesize, compact-database

I have an MS Access front-end (Oracle back-end) that has 2 linked tables, 2 MS Access queries, and 4 reports.

I've noticed that the .accdb files (stored on users' desktops) get bigger over time. They start out at under 1mb after a compact, and end up being 10-20mb after a few months use.

Why is this? There isn't any data stored in the file, so why does it get bigger over time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because (some) temporary data are created in the frontend. It shouldn't matter at all, except if it disturbs you.

You can avoid that completely by making the frontend file *read-only*, but usually it pops a warning message when the user launch the frontend. It will force temporary data to be written to separate files.

Another method is to set the frontend to *compact before closure*. However, that sometimes fail, thus causing more trouble than advantages.

The definitive method to avoid it, is to copy a fresh frontend to user. The user clicks a shortcut to a script that copies the file from the server to a local folder and launch it from the local copy. A script to handle that can be found here:

[Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application in a Citrix environment](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/23959/Deploy-and-update-a-Microsoft-Access-application-in-a-Citrix-environment.html)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this is what I learned :

1. Front-End file size can increase because of a lot or reason and it is important to verify what is the cause. (Memory Leak, Image Management etc)
2. A good deployment architecture is important and will help avoid the file to increase over time:

   - [Good Example of deployment architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738918/how-to-continuously-develop-and-deploy-an-access-2010-database-application)
3. If it is too late and your file have already increased, you can normally return close to the original size with the "Compact and Repair Database" functionality:

   - Open Access in design mode
   - Access Section "Database Tools"
   - Select "Compact and Repair Database"